# Does the current job at time of level up affect the stats gained?

Tags: bravely-default

Whenever you gain a level in Bravely Default, does your current job have a permanent impact on your stat growth as it did in Final Fantasy Tactics?  If so, is there a way to level down and exploit this system as there was in FFT for crazy min-maxing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to say no. There is absolutely no way to level down so no seems like an even more appropriate answer. Since you do not have access to all jobs from the beginning it would only be detrimental to your late game builds. I personally did not notice a distinct difference in magical ability between my characters that were White/Black mage's upon level up compared to me Knight/Swordmaster whenever they switched classes.

Comment: Doing a little more searching, it seams that you are correct in that job at level does not affect stat growth.  I found someone who had leveled characters through the game with completely different jobs and once they were max level, they still had the exact same stats.

Comment: Regarding the second sentence, FF6 had permanent stat boosts on level up depending on the equipped esper, most of which could not be obtained until late in the game. That you can't level down doesn't mean there aren't permanent bonuses that can be lost if you level up too early

Comment: While there is no way to level down, you can turn off experience gains in the Config menu, while leaving Job Points on. In this way, you can ensure that all level ups take place when equipped with a specific job while still leveling up other jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Each job level gained adds +1 to a stat related to the job. I've been tracking this each time I level. In a class like thief I gain +1 Agil, etc.

Comment: Is it a permanent addition or is it only whenever that job is equipped?  I noticed somewhere in the game that an NPC said that the soft stats a job gives you grow as the job level grows saying something about when you first switch jobs you might be weak but the stats grow with the job so don't change jobs all at once (or something to that effect).  That was in Florem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as maxing your stats go I'm thinking best way is to master as many jobs possible while staying at lowest level possible in order to get the most bang for your buck with freelancers late bloomer ability. I could be wrong but I would think more levels to go with those % stat increases in each stat would add up to something. In my game I already have the growth egg and at start of chapter 3 all characters level 32/33 and basically just grinding JP for now so I will let you know how that works.
After looking around the net it seems I was confused in how late bloomer works, so perhaps stat maxing is not possible in this game